# How to replace an Item in scala Map, keeping the order

Tags: scala, dictionary, functional-programming, hashmap

I have a Map like this .

```
  val m1 = Map(1 -> "hello", 2 -> "hi", 3 -> "Good", 4 -> "bad")
  val m2 = Map(1 -> "Great", 3 -> "Guy")
```

Now I need to derive another Map from m1 and m2, and I need to replace elements of m1 by those m2 with order preserved.

`m3` should like

```
   Map(1 -> "Great", 2 -> "hi",  3 -> "Guy", 4 -> "bad")
```

Is there a way to do it in functional programming??

Answer (score 2):

`Map` does not preserve ordering. If you want to preserve insertion order use [`ListMap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/collection/immutable/ListMap.html):

> List map iterators and traversal methods visit key-value pairs in the order they were first inserted.

```scala
val m1 = ListMap(1 -> "hello", 2 -> "hi", 3 -> "Good", 4 -> "bad")
val m2 = Map(1 -> "Great", 3 -> "Guy")
val m3 = m1 ++ m2
```

or [`SortedMap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/collection/immutable/SortedMap.html) if you want ordering by the key:

> An immutable map whose key-value pairs are sorted according to an scala.math.Ordering on the keys.

Comment: Adding that `TreeSeqMap` can be interesting as well, especially for keeping order of Insertion or update rather than a regular Ordering.

Answer (score 1):

```
val m3 = m1 ++ m2
```

However order is not preserved because `Map` is not ordered in the first place. If you want an ordered map use `ListMap`.